# Duplicated Http requests with Observable.ForkJoin in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have an Angular 5 application with the following code in a component:

```
ngOnInit() {

    Observable.forkJoin([
        this.highlightedInsight = this.insightService.getHighlightedInsight(),
        this.insights = this.insightService.getInsightsList(),
        this.topics = this.insightService.getInsightTopicsList()
    ]).subscribe(
        response => {},
        error => {
            console.log('An error occurred:', error);
        },
        () => {
            this.loading = false;
        });

}
```

My html:

```
<div class="internal-wrapper" *ngIf="!loading">
    <app-highlighted-insight [insight]="highlightedInsight | async"></app-highlighted-insight>
    <app-topic-filter [topics]="topics | async"></app-topic-filter>
    <app-insight-list [insights]="insights | async"></app-insight-list>
</div>
```

In my Chrome network tab, each of the 3 API calls is running twice.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be a preflight request. If you see this `Request Method:OPTIONS` in the first request then it's fine.

Comment: Thanks, I had checked that. :-) It's not the preflight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the `async` pipe and the `forkJoin.subscribe` are creating separate network requests.

Use [Observable.share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) to prevent resubscribing

```
this.highlightedInsight = this.insightService.getHighlightedInsight().share()
this.insights = this.insightService.getInsightsList().share()
this.topics = this.insightService.getInsightTopicsList().share()

Observable.forkJoin([
    this.highlightedInsight, this.insights, this.topics
]).subscribe(
    response => {},
    error => {
        console.log('An error occurred:', error);
    },
    () => {
        this.loading = false;
    });
```

---

But because the results aren't needed until the end (when `!loading`), it can be simplified to this:

```
Observable.forkJoin([
    this.insightService.getHighlightedInsight(),
    this.insightService.getInsightsList(),
    this.insightService.getInsightTopicsList()
]).subscribe(
    ([highlightedInsight, insights, topics]) => {
        this.highlightedInsight = highlightedInsight;
        this.insights = insights;
        this.topics = topics;
    },
    error => {
        console.log('An error occurred:', error);
    }
);
```

html:

```
<div class="internal-wrapper">
    <app-highlighted-insight [insight]="highlightedInsight"></app-highlighted-insight>
    <app-topic-filter [topics]="topics"></app-topic-filter>
    <app-insight-list [insights]="insights"></app-insight-list>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s perfect, thank you for explaining what’s going on

Comment: I got this working with .share(), but am looking at the second option you suggested - the syntax is causing me lots of errors, is this line correct: [highlightedInsight, insights, topics]?