# Update child component in Angular based on another child

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm struggling to work out how to solve my use case with Angular.

I have 3 components, a HomeComponent which houses a TopicsFilter component and an ArticlesList component.  I'm trying to update the articles list whenever the user clicks on a new filter option.

My HomeComponent:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    loading = true;
    topics: Observable<Topic[]>;
    articles: Observable<Article[]>;

    public constructor(
        private articleService: Service
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.articles = this.articleService.getArticlesList().share()
        this.topics = this.articleService.getArticleTopicsList().share()

        Observable.forkJoin([
            this.articles, this.topics
        ]).subscribe(
            response => { },
            error => {
                console.log('An error occurred:', error);
            },
            () => {
                this.loading = false;
            });
    }
}
```

My homecomponent html:

```
<app-loader [loading]="loading">
</app-loader>

<div class="internal-wrapper" *ngIf="!loading">
    <app-topic-filter [topics]="topics | async"></app-topic-filter>
    <app-article-list [articles]="articles | async"></app-article-list>
</div>
```

My ArticleList component:

```
export class ArticleListComponent {
    @Input() articles: Article[];
}
```

And finally, my TopicFilter component:

```
export class TopicFilterComponent {
@Input() topics: Topic[] = [];

constructor() { }

select(topic: Topic) {
  this.topics.forEach( (element) => {
    element.active = false;
  });

  topic.active = true;

}
```

So I can get the active topic when the user clicks it, but how do I then get my home component to re run my query with the id of the topic as a paramater and update the List?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `forkJoin`? You're not using the result at all. Also where in your code can we see an example of "query with the id"? I understand what you want to do, but I cannot write a sample code without seeing how do you expect to call the API endpoint with an id parameter.

Comment: The forkjoin means that both api calls are finished before I hide my loading indicator.  It's a result of my earlier question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089420/duplicated-http-requests-with-observable-forkjoin-in-angular-5/48089720#48089720

Comment: With regards to the API code, I'll basically call an endpoint like: articleService.getFilteredArticlesList(topicid)

Comment: But you never instantiate `topics` and `articles`, they are both `undefined`.

Comment: Do you need to instantiate an Observable?  The code works fine, it gets the topics and articles from the web service and only hides the loading indicator and displays them when the Forkjoin completes.   Note also the async pipe in the html markup

Comment: add a output `@Output() updateList: EventEmitter<string>` and emit the event with id in select. Subscribe to it from parent and update the list

Comment: If I update the list on the parent, will the child automatically update?

Comment: yes, it'll update. you can implement `ngOnChanges` to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use outputs.

in your `TopicFilter.component` add the following inside the class

```
@Output() filteredList = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

on filtering you can emit the data

```
this.filteredList.emit(items);
```

now in your `homecomponent html`

```
<div class="internal-wrapper" *ngIf="!loading">
    <app-topic-filter [topics]="topics | async" (filteredList)="getFilteredTopics($event)"></app-topic-filter>
    <app-article-list [articles]="articles | async"></app-article-list>
</div>
```

and in your `ArticleList.component`

```
getFilteredTopics(data) {
  this.articles = data;
}
```

Comment: Needed to do a bit more to get this working, but thanks for putting me on the right path